# SQL Server LIMIT top QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I limit my top query to a certain record.

Example:

The result should be until the value of col2 is b.

```
 ID     col1        col2
  7       1           a
  6       2           a
  5       1           a
  4       3           b
  3       1           a
  2       4           a
  1       1           b
```

Comment: How is this query ordered?

Comment: You surely imply that results are sorted by `col1`, right?  Otherwise the result could be inconsistent.

Comment: No, it looks like you aren't. Are you expressly looking for a random result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM x x1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM x x2
    WHERE x2.rn <= x1.rn
    AND x2.col2 = 'b'
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/625ed/1)

Comment: This is exactly why I asked about order. Same way I would've done it.